# Conserving the result of summing two floats displayed

Tags: jquery, html

I have calculated the sum of two float using jquery,

My problem is : I have a form on multiple pages so when I hit Next to complete the filling of the form and I return to the page where I have summed the floats nothing appear (dont conserve the result).

How can the result remain displayed ?

This is  the code :

```
 <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="value1"  class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label"> value1</label>
        <div  id=" value1"  class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.value1, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for=" value2"  class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label"> value2</label>
        <div  id=" value2" class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.value2, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">Sum</label>
    <span title="sumvalue" id="sumvalue" ></span>
</div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#{{ form.value1.vars.id }}, #{{ form.value2.vars.id }}').keyup(function() {
            $('#sumvalue').html( parseFloat($('#{{form.value1.vars.id }}').val()) +  parseFloat($('#{{ form.value2.vars.id }}').val()));
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the result before pressing next button:
[image]

This is how I get after pressing next button :
[image]

Comment: Can you add the tag about `{{ form_widget(form.value2, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}` come from a pug. may be a jade module?

Comment: you need to store the state yourself, either on the server or in local storage, whatever is appropriate. HTML pages are inherently stateless until you do something about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the values using browser local storage and retrieve it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("product")) {
       $('#sumvalue').html(localStorage.getItem("product"));
    }
    $('#{{ form.value1.vars.id }}, #{{ form.value2.vars.id }}').keyup(function() {
        $('#sumvalue').html( parseFloat($('#{{form.value1.vars.id }}').val()) +  parseFloat($('#{{ form.value2.vars.id }}').val()));
        localStorage.setItem("product", parseFloat($('#{{form.value1.vars.id }}').val()) +  parseFloat($('#{{ form.value2.vars.id }}').val()));
    });
});
```